# Alleged space problems involving creating files in /tmp

Tags: tmp

When trying to open an `epub` file with **Atril Document Viewer** it shows the error:

```
Failed to create directory '/tmp/atril-13933': No Space Left on Device.
```

Similarly, when trying to download a small file (1,4 MB) in Firefox the standard downloader, again a message (roughly translated from my mother language) pops up.

```
There is not enough space available in the disk to save the document
```

After browsing some pages on the Internet, I did: `sudo umount /tmp` and `sudo apt autoremove` but nothing (good) happened.

Then I tried `df -h`. I don't know how to attach images, but there  are a lot of files like those ones:

```
/dev/loop10        172M  172M     0  100% /snap/ungoogled-chromium/6

/dev/loop14        296M  296M     0  100% /snap/vlc/2103

/dev/loop16        281M  281M     0  100% /snap/ungoogled-chromium/7
```

All those `/dev/loop` in the attached image may be created by failed program installation? What is apparent is that `/dev/sda1` has no free space left:

```
/dev/sda1          9,4G  9,1G     0  100% /
```

How can I delete all those `/dev/loop` directories?

TIA.

Comment: Why does the download from a browser not go to your download directory? /tmp is deleted at the time of each reboot that is the point.

Comment: Thanks David. You're right, /tmp is deleted and the problem is not there.

Comment: Do not feel the need to quickly delete the "loop" directories because you happen to see them. They actually may serve a purpose. Your root folder is only 9 GB. That is too small for a typical user. 15 GB is a minimum provided your user data are on another partition.

Comment: Thanks vanadium, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your partitioning. This is your root partition:

`/dev/sda1 9,4G 9,1G 0 100% /`

It is only 9,4 GB. That is too small for a typical user. A fresh Linux install easily fits on that size, but quickly more space will be needed as you install new programs, and as kernels are updated. Moreover, the root directory also contains the temp files (`/tmp`, `/var/tmp`).

You will need to ensure you have a larger root partition. Depending on your current setup, it may be possible to change the size of the current partitions. Else, you may need to reinstall, ensuring that there is sufficient free space for installation to hold a partition of at the very least 15 GB, but better 20 - 25 GB as a minimum.